# How to add or multiply digits of a number

Tags: matlab, addition, algebra

As the title says i want to know if its possible to add or multiply digits of a number in matlab

eg:

for a number

```
123456789
```

add the digits, that is

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 =>45 =>4+5 => 9
```

advance thanks for your help

Comment: Of course its possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

### Numeric approach

```
A  = 35356536576821;
A  = abs(A);
xp = ceil(log10(A)):-1:1;

while ~isscalar(xp)
    A  = sum(fix(mod(A,10.^xp)./10.^[xp(2:end) 0]));
    xp = ceil(log10(A)):-1:1;
end
```

### Char approach

```
A = '35356536576821';
A = char(regexp(A,'\d+','match'));
while ~isscalar(A)
    A = num2str(sum(A - '0'));
end
```

Both, first take the absolute number (strip the minus) then: the numeric one counts with `log10()` how many digits a number has and through modulus and divisions extracts the digits which are summed, while the char approach convert to numeric digits with implicit conversion of  `- '0'`, sums and converts back to string again.

Both approaches might suffer from **floating point approximation**, but the numeric one is definitely more exposed to it:

```
A  = 11111111111111111;
xp = ceil(log10(A)):-1:1;
fix(mod(A,10.^xp)./10.^[xp(2:end) 0])
ans =
  Columns 1 through 13
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
  Columns 14 through 17
     1     1     1     2
```

To have approximations with the char approach, the first sum should exceed a 16 digits number.